# Problems with scale, location and rotation

Tags: mesh

I have a circle mesh and am trying to shear it in a y axis but when I do that my circle here's deformed to a another shape.

I don't know if I messed up with applying scale, rotation and location please help out.[image]

Comment: The issue may not be related to the transforms themselves, I'd try disabling snapping, and set your pivot point to Median Point, it's currently on Bounding Box Center. Then scaling on Y should give you a clean transform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer will try that and give a feedback feedback

Comment: It has worked perfectly thank you